# utf8_general_ci collation error. Tried everything

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

Usual problem. Unusually hard to find a solution.

phpmyadmin server connection collation is set to utf8_general_ci
database collation is set to utf8_general_ci
table collation is set to utf8_general_ci

my .php page has:
before any query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

and page is saved with encoding utf-8.
header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

text without database shows everything correctly, but through database I got what most of us get - ?�?�?�

Have tried almost everything that google offers.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you save the data and what characters would that be? `?�` looks to me like it's actually Unicode and **not** UTF-8

Comment: Data is saved as "mazgāšana" and but shown as "mazg?�ana".

Comment: oh okay, then those are really two characters and my suspicion about Unicode was wrong. But the question remains, *how* do you save this data? Because it's obviously not UTF-8 but some 8 bit encoding.

Comment: Its actually latvian, so I have tried to use utf8_latvian_ci too but nothing is happening.

Comment: How do I save data? I am just inserting it in the database through phpmyadmin. I am just pressing insert tab and filling the values.

Comment: I just checked and every single latvian page is using utf-8 encoding. It has worked for me every time I create simple html website. Just know when I use databases, its showing some wrong characters.

Comment: are the characters displayed correctly within phpmyadmin? And how exactly does your phpmyadmin configuration look like?

Comment: http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4312/screenshot20130308at171.png I just tried to use this mb_detect_encoding($name) and it showed that my encoding is ASCII.

Comment: Yes they are displayed correctly

Comment: Tried $string = utf8_encode($name) and still no result